# In a shell script, run a process in a new terminal, then run something in the original terminal again

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my code:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "some-debug-tool-here"
echo "HELLO"
```

I want the debug tool to run in a new terminal and stay open. That works fine. But I want the command on the next line to run in my terminal, and it never does. I've tried using the `&` after the `gnome-terminal` command but that doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: The & should be enough. It works for me using xterm and sh. `xterm -e sh -c yes &; echo HELLO`

Answer (score 0):

what you can use is nohup

```
nohup test_sample &
```

remember to use "**&**" at the end, you can run any command you want without the need of being in the terminal

if you want to kill the process you just search the PID and kill it

ie `ps aux | grep nohup` `kill 'PID'`

Answer (score 0):

The & should be enough. It works for me using xterm and sh.

```
xterm -e sh -c yes &; echo HELLO
```

–  Raphael Santos